# Need help getting value to refresh in LWC without refreshing browser

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, try-catch

I have an apex class that passes in the value of 'lastCallSource' to do a SOQL query on a Custom MetaData Type that will display a custom field value from the metaData to the user. I have this working, however the error handling does not populate the error to the LWC without refresh. Code and explanations below:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getConfirmSource(String lastCallSource){
System.Debug('LastCallSource = ' + lastCallSource); 
    String company;
    String metaRecord;  
    CustomMeta__mdt myData = new CustomMeta__mdt();
    try { myData = [SELECT Id, Company__c FROM CustomMeta__mdt  WHERE TrackingSource__c =: lastCallSource LIMIT 1]; 
    company = myData.AutoCompany__c;
    metaRecord = myData.Id;  
        System.debug('Leaving the TRY STATMENT'); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('Error creating metadata: ' + e.getMessage());

    }
```

This APEX method is called in the lwc component:

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getConfirmSource from '@salesforce/apex/AgentStateTracker.getConfirmSource';

export default class DisplayCompany extends LightningElement {

    @track company;
    @track error; 

    @api
    lastCallSource;


    @wire(getConfirmSource, {lastCallSource: '$lastCallSource'} )
    wiredMetaData({error,data}){
       if(data){ 
        this.company = data;
        this.error = undefined;


       } else if(error) {
           this.error = error; 
           this.company = 'Unknown'; 


       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said that initially data is correctly shown to user but It is not clear of why you should be getting error.

However, the refresh issue might be because of `cacheable=true`. There are 2 options.

1. Use wire method as above and use `refreshApex()` to refresh cache manually. Below can be done whenever needed in a method:

   ```
   return refreshApex(this.company);
   ```
2. Remove `cacheable=true` and use imperative call (as you cant use wire with non-cacheable method) like below:

.

```
connectedCallback(){
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData(){
    getConfirmSource({ lastCallSource: this.lastCallSource })
      .then(response => --logic--)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: Testing it now. Do you know if you would need to call refreshApex() afterwards? or should the connectedCallBack() method take care of it?

Comment: refreshApex is applicable to wired functions or properties

Comment: Thanks for your help! IT WORKED! If possible, I would give you 100 upvotes! Thanks again.

Comment: WC :) . Pls select solved if solved.

Comment: I marked it as accepted. Is that equivalent?

Comment: yes... it is...